# workaround for Twitter api rate limiting

Tags: ruby, twitter

I've collected a bunch of users and put them in a variable 'users'. I'm looping through them and trying to follow them with my new twitter account. However, after about 15, I'm getting stopped by Twitter for exceeding rate limit.  I want to run this again but without the users that i've already followed. How do I remove 'i' from the array of 'users' after they've been followed, or somehow return a new array out of this with the users I've yet to follow? I'm aware of methods like pop and unshift etc, but I'm not sure where 'i' is coming from within the 'users' array. I'm a perpetual newbie, so please include as much detail as possible

Not, users is actually a 'cursor' and not an array, therefore, it has no length method

```
>> users.each do |i|
?> myuseraccount.twitter.follow(i)
>> end
```

Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests: Rate limit exceeded

Comment: @kyle thanks, that code has this line 'sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in'  how would I set it for 15 minutes?

Comment: Please make the title reflect the *real problem*, which likely isn't about "removing an item", but rather "TooManyRequests when trying to follow on twitter" ..

Comment: @pst toomanyrequests isn't the real problem. i wanted to know how to remove those items from the array, irregardless of the context.

Comment: Then don't include irrelevant content / errors messages ..

Comment: @pst it's not irrelevant to provide context

Comment: Is it an array or a cursor? Also what's a cursor?

Comment: a cursor is some object created by the Twitter api. it's like an array but doesn't have the length method.  That's all i know.

Comment: @user1647484 Considering the accepted answer *has nothing to do with removing items*, please reconsider ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple hack would could make use of a call to [`sleep(n)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep):

```
>> users.each do |i|
?>   myuseraccount.twitter.follow(i)
?>   sleep(3)
>> end
```

Increment the sleep count until `twitter-api` stops throwing errors.

A proper solution to this problem is achieved via `rate-limiting`.

A possible ruby solution for method call rate limiting would be [`glutton_ratelimit`](https://github.com/stungeye/glutton_ratelimit).

Edit - And, as [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640577/kyle) has pointed out, there is [a documented solution to this problem](http://sferik.github.io/twitter/).

Below is an enhanced version of that solution:

```
def rate_limited_follow (account, user)
  num_attempts = 0
  begin
    num_attempts += 1
    account.twitter.follow(user)
  rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
    if num_attempts % 3 == 0
      sleep(15*60) # minutes * 60 seconds
      retry
    else
      retry
    end
  end
end

>> users.each do |i|
?>   rate_limited_follow(myuseraccount, i)
>> end
```

Comment: thanks, but i have one question about Kyle's solution...that code has the line 'sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in'  do you know how I set it for 15 minutes, which is the recommended time to try again?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of a function which implements Kyle's solution with a 15 minute wait period when the rate limit has been exceeded.

Comment: but when it retries, does it continue where it left off? or start at the beginning again?

Comment: In both examples I've shown, it will continue where it left off.

Comment: I'm typing this out in the console and it's giving me an error for dynamic constant assignment

Comment: constants can't be defined inside methods in ruby

Comment: You can move it to a standard variable or configure it elsewhere. Either way, I've fixed the error.

Comment: 'users' is actually a cursor (not an array) and it doesn't have a length method...

Comment: @user1647484 then why does the title of the question refer to removing things from an array? :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of solutions, but the easiest in your case is probably `shift`:

```
while users.length > 0 do
  myuseraccount.twitter.follow(users.first)
  users.shift
end
```

This will remove each user from the array as they are processed.

Comment: @markreed 'users' is actually a cursor (not an array) and doesn't have a length method..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did

```
    def self.careful(&block)

    begin
        client = get_current_client()
        yield client

    rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error

        current_user= User.find_by_token(client.instance_variable_get("@oauth_token"))
        current_user.update_attribute(:rate_limit_at, Time.now)
        change_current_client()
        retry

    end
end
```

this block executes an api call using the current client. If it hits a rate limit, it changes the client to another one using the change_current_client() method, then it retries the call using the new client. you can add a sleep() there if you want.

This can be used like

```
careful{|client| client.search("#something")}
```